# How to click on an item in a list or a library and be able to add more details about it?

Tags: custom-list

I want to create a list where view can look like Employee_Name, Employee_ID, Start_Date. Now if I click on Employee_Name, it should bring up more details about that employee like designation etc. Is it possible to do this SP?

Comment: Yes. Do you want Employee_Name to be "single line of text" or a "person or group" field type?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Designation etc. from View, and Employee_Name can be Title field renamed, once you click Title by default it will open details of the item in popup which will include Designation.

Simply click Title column in List Settings and change the column name to Employee Name.

[Rename Title column in SharePoint List](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/title-column-in-sharepoint-2010-custom-lists.html)